# see call history from a computer

Tags: macos, iphone

Is there a way to access the call history on an iphone from a computer?

My phone has a problem with the display that stops me from using it, it still turns on, but the screen only displays vertical bars, I can tap the screen and it seems to doing something, it makes various sounds that you would expect it to make when tapping the screen, i think i managed to unlock it, but I can't see what is going on.

I plan to take the phone to someone to see if they can fix the display problem. Until then I would like to retrieve a number from the phone that I most recently called. How can I do this?

Also is there a way to redial the previously dialed number, by pressing a combination of buttons without being able to see the screen?

Comment: In the future, please try to ask one question at a time. Both of your questions are legitimate, and can stand by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for question #2: use Siri and ask "Redial last number called." I use it all the time while driving (with a Bluetooth headset, of course!)

Comment: is siri something you have to install or is it there already? i tried a few things, i held down the home button for a bit and it made the noise that it makes when it activates the voice recognition (i never use it but it pops up every now and then), is that siri? i said "redial last number" to it and it didn't seem to understand. after that i tried just "redial" and that didn't work either

Comment: I have an iPhone 5 with the latest iOS (7.1.2), and Siri has its own on/off switch in Settings. Perhaps your phone has the switch set to off. Sorry I can't be of more help

Answer (score 1):

Question 1-

There are multiple apps available to export your iPhone call log.

Example: [Export iPhone’s call logs to computer for storage](http://ios-data-recover.com/export-iphones-call-logs-to-computer-for-storage/)

Question 2- TBD..